# Next.js: How to Refresh the "public" Directory *After* the Server Has Started?

Tags: next.js

In Next.js in production (ie. not using the development server) the contents of the `/public` directory are set at the time the server is started.  In other words, if I start a server with the following files:

- /public
- /public/foo.png
- /public/bar.png

... and I then add a file after (eg. a user uploads it):

- /public/baz.png

Next.js won't serve the new `baz.png` file until the server is restarted.

Is there any way to alert Next to the presence of this file without restarting the entire server?

Comment: Don't know if what you ask is possible but I don't think you can upload to the public folder either so I'm not sure if it is a real problem. If you have some upload functionality, you could send the file to some other storage and retrieve it from there. i.e. AWS S3

Comment: In my case it would be more convenient to upload directly to the public folder rather than using S3.

Comment: From docs: "Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We recommend using a third-party service like AWS S3 for persistent file storage."

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe when https://vercel.com/storage/blob is available